# improper use case of mclapply?

Tags: linux, r, lapply, mclapply

I've been playing with rstudio server on an old laptop with linux mint (debian) installed.

I've always ran on windows, so I've never taken advantage of `parallel` or `multicore` packages, and my goal was to learn `rstudio server` as well as `R linux` and how multicore processing could speed up my processes.

One main use of lapply that I use on an everyday basis looks like this:

```
f <- function(x) {
   x1 <- data[1:50, x]
   x2 <- data[51:100, x]

   line <- c(paste0(mean(x1), " (", sd(x1), ")"),
             paste0(mean(x2), " (", sd(x2), ")"),
             t.test(x1, x2)$p.value)
   return(line)
 }

data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2600, 85, 19), nrow=100, ncol=26))
names(data) <- letters

do.call(rbind, lapply(letters, f))

 microbenchmark(
     do.call(rbind, lapply(letters, f))
 )
```

Median time is `21.8`  milliseconds

Alternatively:

```
library(parallel)
microbenchmark(
     do.call(rbind, mclapply(letters, f))
)
```

Median time is `120.9` milliseconds.

Why this huge difference?

The machine is a 2-core dinosaur. Is it that you do not see benefits until you are working with >= 4-core machines? Is my use case (column wise calculations of a data.frame) improper to see benefits?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is to small to have an advantage against the overhead, try

```
f <- function(x) {
  x1 <- data[1:50000, x]
  x2 <- data[50001:100000, x]

  line <- c(paste0(mean(x1), " (", sd(x1), ")"),
            paste0(mean(x2), " (", sd(x2), ")"),
            t.test(x1, x2)$p.value)
  return(line)
}

data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2600, 85, 19), nrow=100000, ncol=26))
```

instead and check the result. Your example took my laptop 7 and 17 median miliseconds, but my bigger example changes this into 120 and 80. So in my opinion it's (not only) the number of cores, but more the size of your data in this case.

Comment: I just tried this and on my 2-core processor. The gap closed by about 4-tenths of a millisecond, so nothing close to the change you received, but it was at least in the correct direction. I decided to strain the system in both ways by also doubling the number of variables to compute (up to 52), at which point I finally found that mclapply had a faster median compute time. Thanks!